# Voltage fed versus current fed Inverters

Tags: power-electronics, inverter

I would like to ask about voltage fed and current fed inverters.

I know that a voltage fed converter uses a capacitor as the storage device while a current fed converter uses an inductor.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these two topologies and why should someone choose the one over the other?

Comment: May wish to edit your title.  Inverters or converters?  Not all converters are inverters.

Comment: @KH Thanks for your input. I am studying inverters so I edited the question,

Comment: Inductors can provide galvanic isolation and capacitors don't use magnetics would be two reasons.